# Sent email using phpmailer but Outlook attachments count showing incorrect number

Tags: php, outlook, phpmailer

I have implemented the mail functionality using PHP Mailer. Everything is working fine but it is giving wrong attachment count in outlook. I have tested using below code.

```
$mail = new SmtpNotification();
$mail->addAddress("test.email@gmail.com");
$mail->addAttachment($filepath. '/first.xlsx');
$mail->Subject = "Test Subject";
$mail->msgHTML('test Subject');
$mail->send();
echo "mail send";
```

Mail Sent successfully. But I got attachments count 2.
[image]
You can see that there is only 1 attachment but the count of attachments 2 and showing same file 2 times. When I print the object It is showing just 1 attachment.

```
[ReplyToQueue:protected] => Array
    (
    )
[attachment:protected] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /var/www/html/project_name/file/first.xlsx
            [1] => first.xlsx
            [2] => first.xlsx
            [3] => base64
            [4] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
            [5] => 
            [6] => attachment
            [7] => first.xlsx
        )

)
[CustomHeader:protected] => Array
(
)
```

I don't understand why this happening? Is it PHP Mailer issue or outlook issue? and How to solve it? Any help.

The SmtpNotification class is be like

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
class SmtpNotification extends PHPMailer
{
    public function __construct($exceptions = null)
    {
       // Set config data
    }
    public function send()
    {
        if (!empty($this->to) && !empty($this->Body) && !empty($this->From)) {
            return parent::send();
        }
    }
}
```

I had also tried with basic functionality but getting the same.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
// Define all necessary constants here
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->isSMTP();
$email->isHTML(false);
$email->Host = SMTP_HOST;
$email->Port = SMTP_PORT;
$email->SMTPSecure = SMTP_SECURE;
$email->SMTPDebug = SMTP_DEBUG;
$email->SMTPAuth = SMTP_AUTH;
$email->Username = MAIL_FROM_EMAIL;
$email->Password = MAIL_FROM_PASSWORD;
$email->From = MAIL_FROM_EMAIL;
$email->FromName = MAIL_FROM_NAME;
$email->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$email->addAddress("mytest.email@email.com");
$email->addAttachment(Full_File_Path."/second.xlsx");
$email->Subject = "Test Subject";
$email->Body= 'test Body';
$email->send();
echo "mail send";
```

[image]

Still I am getting count 2. I don't understand why is this happening with me.

Comment: It is, obviously, neither caused by PHP Mailer nor by outlook. It is also not caused by the code in your question. That leaves the PHP code that's not in your question. The reason for the doubling must be there. Have a look at your `SmtpNotification` class, how it defines the `addAttachment()` method, and what it does with attachments.

Comment: Set `SMTPDebug = 2` and inspect the actual message being sent.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, All function which I used to show are PHP Mailer core class function. `public function addAttachment(
        $path,
        $name = '',
        $encoding = self::ENCODING_BASE64,
        $type = '',
        $disposition = 'attachment'
    )` Check function on github https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php

Comment: @Synchro I have already check that and also tested with multiple attachments. I have attached 4 files `fourth.xlsx, sec.xlsx, third.xlsx, fifth.xlsx.` but get file count 5 and when click on count `fourth.xlsx` showing 2 times like first.xlsx in attached image

Comment: @Synchro I have added the print result of `$mail` object and it is showing only 1 attachment. also 1 time while debugging

Comment: @KenLee I am sending lots of emails. So instead of writing same code multiple times, I have created class to set config variables like `Host, Port, Username, Password` and override 1 function `send(){if (!empty($this->to) && !empty($this->Body) && !empty($this->From)) { return parent::send();}` But I think this will not effect the attachments. And I have not override the addAttachment().

Comment: I see. (so it extends the PhpMailer class, right ?) Please edit your question to show the SmtpNotification class so that we can speedily check the problem. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update, but still the cause is not in the code we can see, and we don't see all the code. Your `SmtpNotification` class is clearly incomplete, and you say you attach multiple files, yet in your code you only attach one file. How can we check your code when we can't see it? Basically we're asking you to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can include PHPMailer and attachments ourselves, but the rest of the code should be in your question.

Comment: That's not what I said - set `SMTPDebug = 2` and you will see what is *actually* being sent in the raw message structure (each attachment will have its own MIME part), not what is *supposed* to be sent. This will allow you to eliminate (or not) PHPMailer as the cause.

Comment: I tested your SmtpNotification class and send an email with two attachments. My outlook client reports correctly that there are only 2 attachments . Please see the screen dump at this [link](http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/soresult1_24March2022.jpg) . Hence, your problem seems un-reproducible.

Comment: Hi @KenLee I have tested with the core and basic functionality but still happening the same. I have updated the code with and added the basic code(`Hide the config constants`). Thanks!